# How to set default editor tab

Tags: admin, editor

I'd like to have always open the Text tab in editor in administration instead the HTML tab. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier then you thought! Just add this code to the functions.php file in your theme.

```
function prefix_set_default_editor() {
    return 'text';
}
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', 'prefix_set_default_editor' );
```